Check if payment is complete in Django Template
I use django with jinja tempates + frontend. I need to connect QR Code to pay products in the cart. I use official Bank API to create payment, but there is no redirect URL after successed payment, so I need to empty the user's cart after successful payment, but I don't know how. Cart is working on frontend with localStorage and frontend clear cart when user go to payments/success url. But with this method I can't redirect user to this url because QR Code does not support it. How can I check if the payment is successfully done and frontend can clear user's cart?
To be clear, Bank API send callback when the payment is completed, but I don't think if its can help with my problem
I've seen QR code payment on other sites, they somehow knew my payment was successful and showed me a notification + emptied my cart.

Why not doing some polling waiting for callback >
